# video playblack with autobuffer/preload not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, video

I'm not sure if either of these attributes are dated or what, because they are not autobuffering the video as described. I need our video to preload, and avoid any buffering in the middle of playback (2 minute video @ ~70mb over CDN)

```
<%= video_tag ["demo_video.mp4", "demo_video.webm"], :size => "800x450", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true, :type => "video/mp4" %>
```

which outputs:

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" controls="controls" height="450" type="video/mp4" width="800"><source src="demo_video.mp4"><source src="demo_video.webm"></video>
```

I've been throttling the connection, and it doesn't autobuffer or preload any of the video. Is the swift server sending the video unsure of how to throttle, or is there a special way to request it?

Comment: did you try the [preload attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp)?

Comment: @maxpleaner preload: => true still doesn't preload the actual video; when you hit play the buffer bar still follows as you watch. Any ideas?

Comment: hope you dont mind im changing the tags about as this is more of a html question than ruby